# "Recursive hexdump" from command line, input and output with same name

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, hexdump

I have some files in a directory "documents" (file1, file2, ...) and I would like to save them in another directory "documents_hex" with hexdump from command line. There is a way to use hexdump for each file in "documents" and save them in "documents_hex" ("documents_hex" is inside "documents") with the same name in input and output?

Example: file1 to /documents_hex/file1, file2 to /documents_hex/file2, ...

Comment: `cd documents; for file in *; do hexdump "$file" > "/path/to/documents_hex/$file"; done` -- unless your `hexdump` program has a `-o` option to specify the output, or something similar.  (The `hexdump` on Cygwin doesn't have such an option.)

Comment: Thank you! One more doubt: I am using hexdump with -C option. There is a way to keep only the addresses and 16-bytes words?

Comment: I haven't spotted a way using just options to `hexdump`.  You could use `hexdump -C "$file" | sed 's/[[:space:]]*|.*|$//' > "/path/to/documents_hex/$file"` in the body of the loop I suggested.  This uses `sed` to delete the material between two bars, plus spaces immediately before that.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code :

```
for file in `ls documents`
do
  hexdump -x $file > documents_hex/$file
done
```